# Using Jersy API client on appengine

Tags: java, rest, google-app-engine, jersey-client

I have an existing API which internally calls some external API using jersy api client library. I am planning to deploy my API on appengine using with java8, but it seems this jersy library is not functioning on appengine platform, as per google docs either I need to use java.net.URLConnection or urlfetch methods to make http(s) calls from within appengine. Is there a way to make my existing jersy based code work as it is?

Answer (score 0):

The same jersy code worked on appengine platform after adding urlfetch as below in appengine-web.xml

```
  <url-stream-handler>urlfetch</url-stream-handler>
```